# Formula true in one structure, but false in another

Tags: logic

If I have a first-order language L which contains a function symbol $f$ of arity 1 and a relation symbol $R$ of arity 1. Let $\phi$ be $\forall x[R(x) \rightarrow R(f(x))]$.

I need to give an L-structure say, $A$, in which $\phi$ is true but a L-structure, say $B$, in which it is false.

I have tried but I cannot get anywhere with this question.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can't do **either part** of the assignment? Why don't you take the very simplest $L$-structure you can think of, say a one-element structure, and figure out whether $\phi$ is true or false there. Depending on what you find out, call that structure $A$ or $B,$ and you've got **half** of the problem solved!

Comment: I've found a structure $A$ where $\phi$ is true and a structure $B$ where it's false, and **NEITHER OF MY STRUCTURES HAS MORE THAN TWO ELEMENTS.** I think you just need to try a little harder.

Comment: What if I have $A=[\mathbb N^+,f,R]$ and $B=[\mathbb Z,f,R]$ where $f$ sends $x$ to $-x$ and $R$ is the relation on whether $x$ is in the domain or not. Then $\phi$ is true in $B$ but not $A$. It may seem simple, however I struggle to grasp the concepts in logic.

Comment: I don't understand. "$f$ sends $x$ to $-x$" makes sense in $B$ but makes no sense in $A.$ What did you decide about the one-element structure? Is $\phi$ true or false there?

Comment: I assume that means it is wrong. I cannot think of a one element structure where this applies. I have had lectures in this material but i find it hard to apply it to examples.

Comment: What about the structure $A=[S,f,R]$ where $S=\{1\},$ $\ f(1)=1,$ and $R(1)$ is true? Is the sentence $\phi$ true or false in $A$?

Comment: Yes, it's true in A. I never thought about choosing a domain like that. I can now figure about the other false structure. Thanks for your help and time and sorry for running your patience thin!

Comment: Of course you can try to find more *interesting* examples. But I don't think the exercise was meant to be challenging, I think it was just meant to test your basic understanding, so you needn't make it any harder than you have to. I think you can you a two-element structure for $B.$

Comment: Yes, my main issue with logic is the understand of definitions - I get confused between things like language and structure. But thanks for your help, it has cleared up my confusion on this topic.